# How to access vars in theory arithmetic in the user theory plug-ins?

Tags: z3

In the user theory plug-in, suppose I have a customer sort "T" and I defined a function "f" with "`Z3_func_decl`" on T, which takes an argument of sort T and returns sort Int(sort made by "`Z3_mk_int_sort`"). I also have other constraints on the returned Int value.

In the search, I want to capture the concrete value of the Int return value in some callbacks (e.g. `new_assignment` or `new_eq` callbacks) so that I can make additional assertions to solve the argument value of sort T. But the problem is those callback will not be invoked in the search.

I took a look at the `Z3_context` of the SAT solution. In the theory arithmetic, I saw:

> vars: v0    #24   lo:       -oo, up:         4, value:          0,
>   occs:    0, atoms:    1, int , non-base  , shared: 0, activity: 0,
>   unassigned: 0, rel: 1, def: #24

The "#24" is my function and the "4" shown in "up" is the SAT solution of the return value of my function.

My question is how can I get the value "4" in the search. I tried to find it in the equivalence classes of #24 in the callback of `final_check` but no luck there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't do that in Z3. A theory does not have access to the internal datastructures used in other theories. The theories only know whether the shared terms are equal (disequal) or not. 
This design decision allows us to change the implementation of theory without affecting the others. 
The theory of arithmetic is a good example. We will replace the current implementation with a more efficient one. The new implementation will use different datastructures. 
In the example above,  `lo` and `up` are the known lower and upper bounds for term `#24`. 
It is just a coincidence that Z3 selects `4` (the upper bound) as the interpretation for `#24`.

Moreover, in the current version of Z3, the model construction is started after Z3 established the problem to be satisfiable. So, the actual interpretations assigned by the theory arithmetic cannot be really used to help other theories.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Does it mean I have to implement the constraint solving for sort Int in my theory if I want to reason about it? Or is there any ways I can take advantage of the existing Z3 Int solver in my theory? Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide more details about your procedure? How do you want to use the integer constraints in your procedure?

Comment: For example, `T` is a sort of set. `f` is the function returning the size of the set. Suppose given the constraints about the size of the set, I would like to solve the set. Or, with the size of Int, at least I can have some hints about the set. Thanks.

Comment: The current theory plugins only allow users to implement "disjoint" theories. So, to support sets with a size function, I see two options: implement the combined theory (it is a lot of work); implement a plugin that handles the theory of sets without the size function, then implement a wrapper on top of Z3 that implements the combined theory. The wrapper would be essentially implementing the "lemmas on demand" approach, where you check whether the model produced by Z3 is valid or not. If it is not, you add new axioms that prune the model.

Comment: This is a late addition to the answer, but you may be interested in taking a look at our paper "Sets with Cardinality Constraints in Satisfiability Modulo Theories", where we describe a combination very much like what you mentioned. We implemented the algorithm as a theory plugin for Z3, and the paper describes some of these aspects as well. If you think this fits your needs, I'll be happy to provide more details.